# Android: onCreate before OnDestroy between Activities

Tags: android

i have 2 Activities, the end of Activity1 invokes the start of Activity2.
In onDestroy() of Activty1 I do some shit that is importante for Activity2. Not good that Activity2's is onCreate() is called before onDestroy. 
What could I do?

thanks
Nata

Comment: Are you passing data to activity2?

Comment: Why would you want to do 'shit' that is important for Activity2 from Activity1, especially on onDestroy()?  Why can't you move it before you create Activity2, or pass it to Activity2 to do the 'shit' important to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what you need to in `onPause()` instead of `onDestroy()`.  You have no control of when `onDestroy()` will happen, that is completely up to the system.  Even if you call `finish()`, your `Activity` could hang around until the system needs resources.

Comment: This is such a huge issue. Imagine working on a custom framework with dependency on this method..